# Finding suboptimal solution (best solution so far) with Z3 command line tool and timeout

Tags: z3, smt

I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203432/z3-minimization-and-timeout) which spoke about how Z3's python API can be used to get suboptimal solution for a minimization problem

I have a MAXSMT problem, and I want to know how Z3 command line tool can be used to find a suboptimal solution when timeout is specified?

Is using `-t:timeout` option alone suppose to give me a suboptimal solution?

The Z3 solver took 150 seconds to find an optimal solution for my MaxSMT problem

I used `z3 -t:140000 smt2 <filename>` to set the timeout as 140 seconds. But the z3 solver returns unknown (instead of sat and an non zero objective value). I also tried with timeout 145 seconds and saw similar result. When I set timeout as > 150, I got the optimal solution

Am I suppose to add something more to get suboptimal solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `maxres` engine, presented in [νZ - Maximal Satisfaction with Z3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/nbjorner-scss2014.pdf) and [Maximum Satisfiability Using Core-Guided MaxSAT Resolution](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Maximum-Satisfiability-Using-Core-Guided-MaxSAT-Re-Narodytska-Bacchus/67342a0ee114142782633b694ff5cae1f116791a), approaches the optimal solution from the **unsatisfiable region** through a sequence of relaxations. 
Therefore, the `maxres` engine *should not* be able to find any **sub-optimal model**: the first model of the input formula that it finds is also the **optimal model**.

If you don't need a **sub-optimal model** but only a **sub-optimal value**, then you might consider taking the latest approximation of the *upper-bound* value found by `maxres`.

From the command line, it appears that one can make `maxres` print any *lower/upper* bound improvement by enabling the `verbose` option:

```
~$ ./z3 -v:1 smtlib2_maxsmt.smt2 
(optimize:check-sat)
(optimize:sat)
(maxsmt)
(opt.maxsat mutex size: 2 weight: 1)
(opt.maxres [1:2])
(opt.maxres [1:1])
found optimum
is-sat: l_true
Satisfying soft constraints
1: |(not (<= y 0))!1| |-> true 
1: |(not (<= y 0))!2| |-> true 
1: |(not (<= 0 y))!3| |-> false 
sat
(objectives
 (goal 1)
)
(model 
  (define-fun y () Int
    1)
  (define-fun x () Int
    (- 1))
)
```

If I interpret it correctly, in `(opt.maxres [1:2])`, `1` is the latest lower bound and `2` is the latest upper bound for the given objective. Note that in the linked post [Nikolaj Bjorner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203432/z3-minimization-and-timeout) states that `maxres` **may** update the *upper bound* along the `maxres` search, but *I can't tell how frequently that happens so this solution might not be very effective in practice*.

**Alternatively**, you might want to try to use some other *MaxSMT* engine which approaches the optimal solution from the satisfiable region, e.g. `wmax`, though it might be slower than `maxres`.

The MaxSAT engine used by `z3` can be selected using the following option:

```
(set-option:opt.maxsat_engine [wmax|maxres|pd-maxres])
```

One can also set it through the command-line, as follows:

```
~$ ./z3 -v:1 opt.maxsat_engine=wmax smtlib2_maxsmt.smt2 
(optimize:check-sat)
(optimize:sat)
(maxsmt)
(opt.maxsat mutex size: 2 weight: 1)
(opt.wmax [1:2])
(opt.wmax [1:1])
is-sat: l_true
Satisfying soft constraints
1: |(not (<= y 0))!1| |-> true 
1: |(not (<= y 0))!2| |-> true 
1: |(not (<= 0 y))!3| |-> false 
sat
(objectives
 (goal 1)
)
(model 
  (define-fun y () Int
    1)
  (define-fun x () Int
    (- 1))
)
```

Note that there is also an option to enable `wmax` within the `maxres` engine, though I am unsure what it is supposed to do as the output doesn't seem to change:

```
(set-option:opt.maxres.wmax true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me how can I tell z3 from command line to use wmax?