# Performance issues with z3py using modulo and optimization

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm experimenting with Z3 (using the python api) where I'm building up a scheduling model for a class assignment, where I have to use modulo quite often (because its periodic). Modulo seems already to slow down z3 by a lot, but if I try do some optimization on top (minimize a cost function which is a sum), then it takes quite some time for fairly small problems.

Without optimization it works okayish (few seconds for a smaller problem). So that being said, I have now 2 questions:

1) Is there any trick with the modulo function of how to use it? I already assign the modulo value to a function. Or is there any other way to express periodic/ring behavior?

2) I am not interested in finding THE best solution. A good one, will be good enough. Is there a way to set some bounds for the cost function. Like, if know the upper and lower bound of it? Any other tricks, where I could use domain knowledge to find solutions fast. 
Furthermore, I thought that if I ll use timeout option solver.set("timeout" 10000), then the solver would time out with the best solution so far. That doesnt seem to be the case. It just times out.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to comment on the `mod` function without seeing some code. But as a rule of thumb, division is difficult. Are you using `Int` values, or bit-vectors? If you are using unbounded integers, you might want to try bit-vectors which might benefit from better internal heuristics. Or try `Real` values, and then do a proper reduction.

Regarding how to get the "best so far" optimal value, see this answer: [Finding suboptimal solution (best solution so far) with Z3 command line tool and timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437608/finding-suboptimal-solution-best-solution-so-far-with-z3-command-line-tool-and)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the built-in modulo and division, you could introduce uninterpreted functions `mymod` and `mydiv`, for which you only provide the necessary axioms of division and modulo that your problem requires. If I remember correctly, Microsoft's Ironclad and/or Ironfleet team did that when they had modulo/division-related performance problems (using the pipeline Dafny -> Boogie -> Z3).